# How to know whether an object is proxy?

Tags: javascript

How to know whether an object is proxy?

```js
function A(n){this.n=n;};

let a = new A(1);
let p = new Proxy(a,{});

console.log('p.constructor == Proxy; // ', p.constructor == Proxy);
console.log('p.constructor == A; // ', p.constructor == A);

console.log('Proxy.prototype: ', Proxy.prototype); // null

console.log('Object.getPrototypeOf(p) == Object.getPrototypeOf(a); // ', 
 Object.getPrototypeOf(p) == Object.getPrototypeOf(a));

console.log('\n');
```

Comment: --`p instanceof Proxy`?-- nope. Doesn't work

Comment: I meaned "to know" instead of 'to define". :)

Comment: @evolutionxbox no, it doesn't work for `Proxy`.

Comment: See [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/javascript/comments/4wrdxd/how_to_find_if_an_object_is_a_proxy/)

Comment: Unless you define your own mechanism (may overload the proxy constructor with a getter that returns true for a specific *Symbol* ) , it is not possible